Ring opening polymerization of polylactic acid using tin(II) 2-ethylhexanoate
I am writing my thesis on polymerization of pla. i used following method: https://www.chimia.ch/chimia/article/view/2012_951/4616
I am writing theory about the ROP of polylactic acid  using the catalyst tin(II) 2-ethylhexanoate and I cannot find any papers describing the specific reaction mechanism of the synthesis.
Does anyone know of a paper or any illustration/explenation of the ROP using this specific catalyst?
Sources would be very much appreciated.
Thank you for your help

You seem to have a surprising misunderstanding. It's synthesis of polylactic acid via ROP of lactide. Nobody makes lactide using ROP. It's not even polycondensation, because it's just 2 molecules condensed into a ring that later is opened during polymerisation.

Hey @Mithoron, thank you for spotting my mistake in the post which has bin corrected. As for the lactide ROP I just made a small mistake because I mistook a coordination insertion described in some papers for an ROP just out of sloppy reading. And the polycondensation I meant to say was used for synthetisation of the prepolymer. Anyways thank you
